# Incorrect Notification Badge Count on Android Devices with Expo React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

### Affected Versions:

```
Expo SDK: 50
React Native: 0.73
react-native-onesignal: 5.0.3
onesignal-expo-plugin: 2.0.2
```

### Description:

Currently, there's an issue with the OneSignal integration in Expo React Native applications specifically on Android devices. The problem arises when a notification is received on the device. Instead of accurately reflecting the number of notifications in the badge count, it displays a count that is one higher than the actual number of notifications present in the notification center.

### Steps to Reproduce:

Set up an Expo React Native application.
Integrate OneSignal for push notifications.
Send a notification to the device.
Observe the badge count displayed on the app icon.

### Expected Behavior:

The badge count on the app icon should accurately reflect the number of notifications present in the notification center. For example, if there is one notification in the notification center, the badge count should display as 1.

### Current Behavior:

Upon receiving a single notification, the badge count on the app icon displays as 2 instead of 1.

### Additional Information:

This issue is specific to Android devices.
The problem persists even after updating to the latest versions of Expo SDK, React Native, react-native-onesignal, and onesignal-expo-plugin.
This issue is not observed on iOS devices.

### Note:

This issue was encountered in a production environment and significantly impacts user experience. Any assistance or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.